# npm build error for Keen Bootstrap premium template

Tags: npm, webpack, build

I just purchased the Keen theme from Bootstrap and whilst following the instructions to the letter I ran into an error executing 'npm run build' (see below). I've looked at the web pack.config.js file (see below), but as it's something I've not looked at in depth I can't figure out where the problem is. Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Error output:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'build' ]
2 info using npm@6.13.6
3 info using node@v13.8.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle keen@1.4.2~prebuild: keen@1.4.2
6 info lifecycle keen@1.4.2~build: keen@1.4.2
7 verbose lifecycle keen@1.4.2~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle keen@1.4.2~build: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/julian/Downloads/compile/node_modules/.bin:/Users/julian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/bin:/Users/julian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@global/bin:/Users/julian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/bin:/Users/julian/.cargo/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public/:/Users/julian/.rvm/bin
9 verbose lifecycle keen@1.4.2~build: CWD: /Users/julian/Downloads/compile
10 silly lifecycle keen@1.4.2~build: Args: [ '-c', 'webpack' ]
11 silly lifecycle keen@1.4.2~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle keen@1.4.2~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: keen@1.4.2 build: `webpack`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:321:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:321:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1026:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid keen@1.4.2
15 verbose cwd /Users/julian/Downloads/compile
16 verbose Darwin 19.3.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v13.8.0
19 verbose npm  v6.13.6
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error keen@1.4.2 build: `webpack`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the keen@1.4.2 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

webpack.config.js:

```
/**
 * Main file of webpack config.
 * Please do not modified unless you know what to do
 */
const path = require("path");
const glob = require("glob");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const fs = require("fs");
const parser = require("comment-parser");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const WebpackRTLPlugin = require("webpack-rtl-plugin");
const TerserJSPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");
const WebpackMessages = require("webpack-messages");
const ExcludeAssetsPlugin = require("webpack-exclude-assets-plugin");
const atob = require("atob");
const slash = require("slash");
const del = require("del");

// optional
const ReplaceInFileWebpackPlugin = require("replace-in-file-webpack-plugin");

/**
 * Known issues:
 * 1) Remove webpack bootstrap for single-module apps
 *      https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2638
 */

// arguments/params from the line command
const args = {};
// remove first 2 unused elements from array
const argv = JSON.parse(process.env.npm_config_argv).cooked.slice(2);
argv.forEach((arg, i) => {
    if (arg.match(/^--/)) {
        const next = argv[i + 1];
        args[arg] = true;
        if (next && !next.match(/^--/)) {
            args[arg] = argv[i + 1];
        }
    }
});
// read parameters from the command executed by user
const rtl = args["--rtl"] || false;
const prod = args["--prod"] || false;
const css = args["--css"] || true;
const js = args["--js"] || true;

// theme name
const themeName = "keen";
// global variables
const release = true;
const apiUrl = false; // boolean
const rootPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "..");
const frameworkPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "..");
const distPath = rootPath + "/dist";
const configPath = rootPath + "/tools";
const assetDistPath = distPath + "/assets";
const srcPath = rootPath + "/src/assets";

// page scripts and styles
const pageScripts = glob.sync(srcPath + "/js/pages/**/!(_*).js");
const pagesScss = glob.sync(srcPath + "/sass/pages/**/!(_*).scss");

const extraPlugins = [];
const filesConfig = [];
const imageReference = {};
const exclude = [];
const nodeMedia = [];

// remove older folders and files
// (async () => {
//     await del.sync(assetDistPath, {force: true});
// })();

// get all assets config
let files = glob.sync(configPath + "/webpack/**/*.js");

// parse comments to get the output location
files.forEach((filename) => {
    // get file content
    const text = fs.readFileSync(filename).toString();
    // use parser plugin to parse the comment.
    const parsed = parser(text);
    if (parsed.length > 0 && parsed[0].tags.length > 0) {
        // push to list
        filesConfig.push({
            filename: filename,
            params: parsed[0].tags,
        });
    }
});

const entries = {};
filesConfig.forEach((file) => {
    let output = "";
    file.params.forEach((param) => {
        // get output path
        if (param.tag === "output") {
            output = param.name;
        }
    });
    entries[output] = file.filename;
});

// process skin scss
const skinScss = glob.sync(srcPath + "/sass/**/skins/**/!(_*|style*).scss");
skinScss.forEach((file) => {
    const matched = file.match(/sass\/global\/layout\/(.*?)\.scss$/);
    if (matched) {
        entries["css/skins/" + matched[1].replace(/\/skins\//, "/")] = file;
    }
});

// process pages scss
pagesScss.forEach((file) => {
    const matched = file.match(/\/(pages\/.*?)\.scss$/);
    if (matched) {
        // keep image reference for output path rewrite
        const imgMatched = fs.readFileSync(file).toString().match(/['|"](.*?\.(gif|png|jpe?g))['|"]/g);
        if (imgMatched) {
            imgMatched.forEach((img) => {
                img = img.replace(/^['|"](.+(?=['|"]$))['|"]$/, '$1');
                imageReference[path.basename(img)] = "css/" + matched[1] + ".css";
            });
        }
        entries['css/' + matched[1]] = file;
    }
});

// auto get page scripts from source
pageScripts.forEach(function (jsPath) {
    const matched = jsPath.match(/js\/(pages\/.*?)\.js$/);
    entries["js/" + matched[1]] = jsPath;
});

if (release) {
    // copy html by demo
    extraPlugins.push(new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
        from: rootPath + "/src",
        to: distPath,
    }]));
}

if ((/true/i).test(rtl)) {
    // enable rtl for css
    extraPlugins.push(new WebpackRTLPlugin({
        filename: "[name].rtl.css",
    }));
}

if (!(/true/i).test(js)) {
    // exclude js files
    exclude.push('\.js$');
}

if (!(/true/i).test(css)) {
    // exclude css files
    exclude.push('\.s?css$');
}

if (exclude.length) {
    // add plugin for exclude assets (js/css)
    extraPlugins.push(new ExcludeAssetsPlugin({
        path: exclude
    }));
}

if (apiUrl) {
    // replace api url to point to server
    extraPlugins.push(new ReplaceInFileWebpackPlugin([{
        dir: assetDistPath + "/js",
        test: /\.js$/,
        rules: [{
            search: /inc\/api\//i,
            replace: 'https://keenthemes.com/' + themeName + '/tools/preview/'
        }]
    }]));
}

const mainConfig = function () {
    return {
        // enabled/disable optimizations
        mode: (/true/i).test(prod) ? "production" : "development",
        // console logs output, https://webpack.js.org/configuration/stats/
        stats: "errors-warnings",
        performance: {
            // disable warnings hint
            hints: false
        },
        optimization: {
            // js and css minimizer
            minimizer: [new TerserJSPlugin({}), new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})],
        },
        entry: entries,
        output: {
            // main output path in assets folder
            path: assetDistPath,
            // output path based on the entries' filename
            filename: "[name].js"
        },
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                "morris.js": "morris.js/morris.js",
                "jquery-ui": "jquery-ui",
            }
        },
        plugins: [
            // webpack log message
            new WebpackMessages({
                name: themeName,
                logger: str => console.log(`>> ${str}`)
            }),
            // create css file
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                filename: "[name].css",
            }),
            // copy media
            new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
                from: srcPath + "/media",
                to: assetDistPath + "/media",
            }]),
            {
                apply: (compiler) => {
                    // hook name
                    compiler.hooks.afterEmit.tap('AfterEmitPlugin', (compilation) => {
                        filesConfig.forEach((file) => {
                            let output = "";
                            file.params.forEach((param) => {
                                // get output path
                                if (param.tag === "output") {
                                    output = param.name;
                                }
                                if (param.tag === "images") {
                                    param.name.split(",").forEach((file) => {
                                        if (file) {
                                            const outputPath = assetDistPath + "/" + pathWithoutFile(output) + "/images/";
                                            // create dir
                                            fs.mkdirSync(outputPath, {recursive: true});
                                            // copy image
                                            fs.copyFileSync(fs.realpathSync(srcPath + "/" + file), outputPath + path.basename(file));
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    });
                }
            },
        ].concat(extraPlugins),
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: [
                        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        "css-loader",
                    ],
                },
                {
                    test: /\.scss$/,
                    use: [
                        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        "css-loader",
                        {
                            loader: "sass-loader",
                            options: {
                                sourceMap: true,
                                // // use for separate css pages (custom pages, eg. wizard, invoices, etc.)
                                // includePaths: demos.map((demo) => {
                                //     return slash(srcPath) + "/sass/theme/demos/" + demo;
                                // })
                            }
                        },
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(ttf|otf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
                    include: [
                        path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"),
                        rootPath,
                        frameworkPath,
                    ],
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: "file-loader",
                            options: {
                                // prevent name become hash
                                name: "[name].[ext]",
                                // move files
                                outputPath: "plugins/global/fonts",
                                // rewrite path in css
                                publicPath: "fonts",
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g)$/,
                    include: [
                        path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"),
                        rootPath,
                    ],
                    use: [{
                        loader: "file-loader",
                        options: {
                            // prevent name become hash
                            name: "[name].[ext]",
                            // move files
                            outputPath: (url, resourcePath) => {
                                // look for node_modules plugin
                                const matched = slash(resourcePath).match(/node_modules\/(.*?)\//);
                                if (matched) {
                                    for (let i = 0; i < filesConfig.length; i++) {
                                        if (filesConfig[i].filename.match(new RegExp(matched[1]))) {
                                            let output = "";
                                            filesConfig[i].params.forEach((param) => {
                                                // get output path without filename
                                                if (param.tag === "output") {
                                                    output = pathWithoutFile(param.name);
                                                }
                                            });
                                            nodeMedia[url] = output + "/images/" + url;
                                            return output + "/images/" + url;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                // the rest of images put in media/misc/
                                return "media/misc/" + url;
                            },
                            // rewrite path in css
                            publicPath: (url, resourcePath) => {
                                if (imageReference[url]) {
                                    // fix image rewrite path
                                    const filePath = pathWithoutFile(imageReference[url]);
                                    return slash(path.relative(assetDistPath + "/" + filePath, assetDistPath + "/media") + "/" + url);
                                }
                                if (nodeMedia[url]) {
                                    return "images/" + url;
                                }
                                return "../../media/misc/" + url;
                            },
                        }
                    }]
                },
            ]
        },
        // webpack dev server config
        devServer: {
            contentBase: distPath,
            compress: true,
            port: 3000
        }
    }
};

module.exports = function () {
    return [mainConfig()];
};

function pathWithoutFile(filname) {
    return filname.substring(0, filname.lastIndexOf("/"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just realized I forgot to include the src directory in the same parent directory as the included tools directory (:face_palm!)